# Laravel where has on last record

Tags: laravel, laravel-6.2

Here is the current query I'm trying to execute

```
Statement::whereHas('history',  function ( $query) use ($end) {
                $query->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::parse($end))->latest()->limit(1)->where('read_flag', '=', 0);
            });
        })->get()
```

I'm trying to get some statements where the latest history value has a `read_flag = false`.

- If the latest value has a `read_flag = false` the model should be
  returned.
- If the a statements latest history value has a `read_flag = true` a
  model shouldn't be returned even if there are older histories with a
  `read_flag = false`.

At the moment the query I'm doing still returns older values with a `read_flag = false` when I only want to query the latest record only. Any ways of achieving this?

The `$end` value I'm using is `2020-02-09 23:59:59`

When using the query I have to records setup.

This record is the newer record with `read_flag = true`

```
"id":77,
"statement_id":4,
"statement_version_id":4,
"read_count":1,
"unread_count":0,
"read_flag":1,
"created_at":"2020-02-09 12:16:23",
"updated_at":"2020-02-10 12:16:23"
}
```

This record is the older record with `read_flag = false`

```
"id":65,
"statement_id":4,
"statement_version_id":4,
"read_count":0,
"unread_count":2,
"read_flag":0,
"created_at":"2020-02-07 13:25:06",
"updated_at":"2020-02-07 13:25:06"
}
```

So when running the query I'd expect no statements to be returned because the latest record has `read_flag = true`

However this is the output I get

```
{
"id":4,
"site_id":9786,
"team_id":9421,
"name":"ds",
"company_statement_id":1,
"current_statement_version_id":4,
"system_company_statement_id":null,
"created_at":"2020-02-03 10:17:13",
"updated_at":"2020-02-03 10:17:13",
}
```

Comment: $end is a variable that I use so I can see select records from older periods. When using this query I'm passing '2020-02-09 23:59:59'

Comment: can you please update answer and write your actual input and out put with expected result or also you can try with `whereDate()` instead of `where()`

Comment: whereDate() didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-subquery-enhancements

Comment: The problem here  `->latest()->limit(1)->where('read_flag', '=', 0)` you think that you're getting the last record then checking it's flag but that's not what happens , the query match the where conditions first then try to gets the last record.

Comment: Cool, I understand. Is there any way around this?

Comment: As far as I know there is no built-in eloquent solution for what you are trying to achieve, but I'll write an example for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no built-in eloquent function that gives you this kind of behaviour.

However you can filter your collection after retrieval and reject the elements that doesn't match your criteria, like this (code is not tested):

```
$statements = Statement::whereHas('history', function ($query) use ($end) {
    $query->where([
        ['created_at', '<', Carbon::parse($end)],
        ['red_flag', 0]
    ]);
})
->get()
->reject(function($element) use($end) {
    $latestHistory = $element->history()->latest()->first();
    return (Caron::parse($latestHistory->created_at)->gte(Carbon::parse($end)) || $latestHistory->red_flag !== 0);
});
```

**EDIT: Fixed some code typos.**

Comment: For improved efficiency you can load the last history element in your eloquent query using the `with` function, making this a single database query instead of an extra query for each statement record (when fetching last history in the reject function).